# Pod Bay bug, or SE chat feature by design?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, chat

I don't think the pod bay has a "meta" so I'll try to ask here?

I dropped this link into the pod bay, hoping to see the link in blue font. Instead I got a vanity picture of Matt Damon and a summary of a Wikipedia article.

The stackexchange chat function overrode my link and plopped a big thing in its place that I didn't want there. Is this a *chat-bug* or a *chat-feature by design*?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Damon#Early_years:_1988.E2.80.931996

But all I got is this lousy photo:

[image]

**Please do not** add the `bug` tag to my question! It attracts people who come and zero-out the question by adding the `by-design` tag. I do not know if this is a bug yet or not, this is why I'm asking the question.

I'm not prepared yet for the *by-design tag-putters!*

Comment: It's not a bug. I'd add [status-by-design], but I suspect that won't be welcome. If you want to avoid [the onebox effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57286/1438) put something else in the chat item: `Look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Damon#Early_years:_1988.E2.80.931996`

Comment: If you click the "Matt Damon" link, it takes you to that exact link.  It just turns the link into a preview.

Comment: @JonEricson that's exactly the answer I needed, thanks! If you can leave it as such I can accept it and close this off. I or you can also adjust the question if it helps. Movie stars get their mug exposed offen enough. :)

Comment: FWIW, I'm not exactly sure why you would want to avoid this effect, for the reason Phiteros mentioned.

Comment: @called2voyage the link I pasted was a link to a specific sub-section of the article - the part where he drops out of Harvard. I was hoping for just a one-line link, not a big block of irrelevant text and a mug shot of a movie star. I didn't realize that if you include the link with text it shows as a normal style link, but if you don't type some stuff, it will summon an unwanted/unexpected banner and photo. Imagine every time you want to add a link to a subsection of some text a UI decides to put a giant banner and photo.

Comment: @JonEricson I've recovered sufficiently, feel free to "by-design" me ;-)

Comment: Okie doke. Added. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in @JonEricson's [comment](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/users/406/jon-ericson), this is how it is meant to work, and so in their infinite wisdom the OP was correct in not including the [bug](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) tag.

When you paste a bare url, apparently it is ayor. If there is a picture of Matt Damon associated with it, we'll have to see him again.

Most of the time this won't happen; paste a bare link to most news articles and only the url shows up. Post a url to an image, and the image shows up.

But paste a bare url to a Wikipedia site or some other sites such as those [on this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57287/303080) and the onebox effect may be invoked.

As also mentioned in that comment, if you add something else to the line along with the url that's not interpreted as a part of the url, such as `See: url`  or `@user url` then you can rest assured that your chat post will remain Matt Damon-free.