# The Pod Bay used to show tweets, now it doesn't seem to for me, why?

Tags: support, chat

In [The Obervatory](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/815/the-observatory) it looks like this:

[image]

but in [The Pod Bay](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/the-pod-bay) it's only a url.

[image]

I think the Pod Bay used to show tweets as tweet-like, just like it shows [photos of Matt Damon even when you don't want them](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803/12102). But now that function seems to be turned off, even though XKCD has unthrottled auto-pipeline privleges of full-size cartoons.

Is this so? If so, why?

Comment: Related: [Onebox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/onebox/info)

Comment: @AndrewT. oh that's an excellent use of a tag wiki as well. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not so. I've been bitten once again by the "Matt Damon bug".

If you paste the naked url you get the full thing. If it's embedded with other text, you don't. That's all. End of story, nothing to see here, etc.

Test in the Pod Bay verifies this answer:

[image]

Comment: I'd thought shortened-URL is prohibited throughout the SE sites?

Comment: @BoostedNub what made you think that, can you find a link to where you read it?

Comment: Well not exactly "throughout" should be said. But that happened to me once when I tried to post an answer and attach it with a link in shortened-URL format. I was forbidden to post that answer unless I change the link to the format that is embedded with other texts as you said. Probably chat room is not the case.